# How to disable Lantern from startup?

Tags: macos, startup

I installed Lantern a while back and I cannot find option to turn it off from startup and it is not in my Login Items list in my Users & Groups. I like to know how to disable lantern from startup.

OS X 11.11.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do it from UI.

Click on settings icon on the bottom right of lantern browser window:

[image]

You can disable auto-startup there.

If that doesn't work, try the following:

Try setting autolaunch to false in lantern config

~/Library/Application\ Support/Lantern/lantern-2.0.10.yaml

```
version: 3
cloudconfig: http://config.getiantem.org/cloud.yaml.gz
cloudconfigca: ""
addr: 127.0.0.1:8787
role: client
instanceid: 9b965155-2908-4292-b379-69f968f890f1
cpuprofile: ""
memprofile: ""
uiaddr: 127.0.0.1:16823
autoreport: true
autolaunch: true
stats:
  reportingperiod: "0"
  statshubaddr: pure-journey-3547.herokuapp.com
server:
  unencrypted: false
  country: ""
  registerat: ""
  portmap: 0
  frontfqdns: {}
  waddelladdr: ""
```